# Google authentication is redirecting to http version of my site

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth, google-oauth, passport.js, passport-google-oauth

I am implementing google authentication on my [blog](https://www.frustratedprogrammer.in/) application which is on react.

I am hitting [this URL](https://blog.frustratedprogrammer.in/api/auth/google) to invoke google authentication and my callback URL is `/api/auth/google/callback`.

However , i am running into two issues.

1. I am getting redirect mismatch error , where the redirect_URI is showing as [http://www.blog.frustratedprogrammer.in/](http://blog.frustratedprogrammer.in/) instead of https://blog.frustratedprogrammer.in/.

however , i have configured https version in my env variables.

2. sometimes , i am getting `Missing required parameter: scope` error.

I will provide my passport.js implementation along with my API routes , please look into this and ask for any additional info required.

```
//passport.js file
passport.use(
  new Google(
    {
      clientID: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
      callbackURL: "/api/auth/google/callback",
    },
    function (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
      UserModel.findOne({ googleId: profile.id }, function (err, user) {
        if (err) return done(err);
       // my server side logic
    }
  )
);
```

```
router.get(
  "/google",
  passport.authenticate("google", { scope: ["profile", "email"] })
);

router.get(
  "/google/callback",
  passport.authenticate("google", { failureRedirect: "/auth/login/failed" }),
  function (req, res) {
    // Successful authentication, redirect home.
    const { password, ...other } = req.user._doc;
    req.session.user = other; // Store user details in session
    res.redirect(process.env.CLIENT_ORIGIN);
  }
);
```

and my client origin is CLIENT_ORIGIN=https://www.frustratedprogrammer.in/ and this is perfectly working fine on my localhost. only problem occurs when i use this on prod.

I have tried hardcoding the auth callback as mentioned in this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70711876/my-https-website-after-google-auth-redirects-to-http) solution but it is creating few more issues.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with the redirect URI mismatch (http://www.blog.frustratedprogrammer.in/ instead of https://blog.frustratedprogrammer.in/) might be due to how your server is configured or how you're handling HTTPS. Make sure your server is correctly configured to handle HTTPS requests and redirects.

Check if there are any proxy servers in front of your Express server that might be causing the URL to change.

Comment: all my requests are going to https only , but i don't know how this is going to http

Comment: try to implement error handling  and also 
 (req, res, next) => {
    console.log("Google Client ID:", ..);
    console.log("Google Client Secret:", ...);
    console.log("Scope:", ["profile", "email"]); // Ensure this array is correct
    next(); }
 then do 
  passport.authenticate("google", { scope: ["profile", "email"] })